# Javascript object binding in .NET MVC 5 and server side validation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a class in my project which looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   [Required]
   public string keyword { get; set; }
   public string saleRange { get; set; }
}
```

This is how the action looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Analyze")]
    public ActionResult Analyze(MyClass obj)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json("error");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("ok");
        }
    }
```

And in jQuery:

```
  $(document).on("click",".btnAnalyze",function() {
        var data =
        {
            keyword: $(".keywordInput").val(),
            saleRange: "1"
        };
        console.log($(".keywordInput").val());
        $.post("/Controller/Analyze",data).done(function(){
            if (data == "error") {
                alert("all fields are required");
            }
        });
    });
```

As you can see I'm mapping a JS object to a C# class object which I pass to my action. Now what the problem here is, even if I don't supply anything for the keyword property (ie. it's null or ""), the ModelState still shows it's property IsValid as true, but it should be set on false if I don't pass anything as keyword parameter.

This is first part of the problem, the other question I have here is how would I, If I have 10 textbox field, of which all are required. And if user enters only 1/10 of those, I would like to send a message for the first next field user has to validate in order to proceed, like "texbox #2 is required, please enter something" instead of a just general message like "all fields are required" or something like that ?

Can someone help me out with this ?

Why does the modelstate shows the it's valid even though after I dont' supply keyword parameter in the object?

@T.Jung here Is a sample of input:

```
 <input placeholder="Enter keywords" class="form-control keywordInput" type="text" style="width:80%">
```

It's basically just a plain input field in html..

Comment: Why are you doing your validation via an alert? Can't you just use the ModelErrors and the ValidaitionMessage from the HtmlHelper?

Comment: @T.Jung it's just a simple message so that I can know whether the validation passed or not ... Could you show me an example of those? I don't recall using them before

Comment: Can you add some coed of your view where you create one input field?

Comment: @T.Jung I added one , specifically the keyword field which I'm trying to perform a validation against, and that field is wrapped up in a form tag...

Answer (score 3):

You can use form validation, which will perform data annotation validation on the client side and you do not have to go to the server side.

```
 $('#btnAnalyze').on('click', function (evt) {
    if ($('#YourformId').valid()) {
       //Perform AJAX call
    }
```

This way if any of the validations do not work, the form.valid() will throw the data annotation errors. So you can add Required to those fields in the models and it will ensure data is not sent if validation fails.

Comment: Does this returns information in regards to which fields aren't validated properly?

Comment: Yeah it should work the same way the data annotations work.

Comment: It says: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function

Comment: Okay I got it, I had to reference a few libs here n there... But the ModelState still shows it's validated (true) even after I pass the first parameter as null ?

Comment: Wait, if you have that if condition, It should not go to the AJAX call itself. Do you have <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script> in your view?

Comment: No no it doens't goes with the ajax call itself, rather i perform validation check on button click event, if the validation goes through , only then post goes through...

Comment: Yes all those are there, perhaps I should do an AJAX call instead of jquery post ??

Comment: Check Pete's answer. It is basically the entire code of what I wanted you to do.

Comment: yes it's a good answer, just I honestly dislike the Html.ValidationMessageFor and what it outputs is just a plain string, I wanted to show a bit more fancier error messages than that... Are they possible to be modified if needed to show a bit better error messages?

Comment: [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")] Put this on top of your model property and change Name to whatever is required.

Comment: Sure thanks for the info, but is there any way to custom/modify how the messages display, like displaying a little popup above the textbox or something like that ?

Or does that purely depends on my CSS and design skills ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that using data annotations. But you can do what you need using Javascript, should be a number of examples available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, do you have any links where I should start in regards to that ? :)

Comment: Nope, Guess you have to search around for that.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

1. Make sure your script bundle includes the following 2 files after your jquery and in this order:

   - jquery.validate.js
   - jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
2. Create your partial / view for your form:

```cshtml
@model MyClassObject

<form action="/action" method="post" id="form">
    <div class="row">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Param1)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Param1, new { @class = "label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Param1, new { @class = "textbox" })
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Param2)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Param2, new { @class = "label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Param2, new { @class = "textbox" })
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Param3)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Param3, new { @class = "label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Param3, new { @class = "textbox" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

3. Do you server side validation

```csharp
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("action")]
public ActionResult action(MyClassObject obj)
{
   if(!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return action(); // this is your original action before you do the post
   }
   else
   {
      // do your processing and return view or redirect
      return View(); // or redirect to a success page
   }
}
```

4. Add the error message to your class:

```csharp
public class MyClassObject
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a keyword")]
   public string keyword { get; set; }
   public string saleRange { get; set; }
}
```

5. Your js validation will be plumbed in now but you will need to stop the form from posting and check the validation before doing your ajax request:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form'), // get a normal js form (I do this just so I can pass in the method and action dynamically - seems better than using .attr() to get them
    jqForm = $(form);

jqForm.on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (jqForm.valid()) {
    var formData = jqForm.serializeArray(); // I use serializeArray so I can add extra values if I need to, you can use serialize() 
    // formData.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value }); - optional for adding extra data 

    $.ajax({
      url: form.action,   // this can be just a specific json url if you just need to get some json - it doesn't have to be the same url as the fallback (no js url)
      type: form.method,
      data: formData,
      success: function(result) {
         // do success stuff!
      }
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Pete yes good point, probably it's for the best that I use built in features of MVC rather than trying to find a workaround for something that works good , thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

> You should stringify the JavaScript Object in the Jquery post

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: In this case then both parameters are nulll

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the Validation on server side:

**Contoller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Analyze")]
public ActionResult Analyze(Model viewModel)
{
    if(viewModel.PropertyName.IsNullOrEmpty()){
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyName", "The Field InputFieldName neeeds to be filled!");
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Do what ever you want with your Inofrmation
        //return a redirct or anything else
    }
    //If you got here some fields are not filled
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PropertyName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PropertyName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
//@class = "text-danger" only if you're using bootstrap
```

I do all of my validation this way.